# Injecting object properties or methods using Zend 2 dependency injection (Zend\DI\DI)

Tags: php, dependency-injection, zend-framework2

I am currently using a similar class to Pimple for managing dependency injection. For example, if I want to retrieve an instance of a database connection who is dependant on a configuration class, I would do:

```
$DI = new DIContainer;

$DI->Config =
     $DI->share = function($c){
           return new Config;
     };

$DI->Database =
     $DI->share = function($c){

          $cfg = $c->Config;

          $host = $cfg->getDbHost();
          $username = $cfg->getDbUsername();
          $password = $cfg->getDbPassword();
          $name = $cfg->getDbName();

          return new \mysqli($host, $username, $password, $name);
     };
```

In simplest terms: $DI->Config always returns the same instance of the configuration class, and $DI->Database will always return the same database connection, by injecting not the Config object itself, but several properties of the object (host, user, etc.).

Of course, this means having to setup the container at runtime and I was thinking of shifting to Zend Framework 2's dependency injection container (which allows passing a definition list).

However, I can't find an example on how to inject object properties, rather than the object itself, in Zend\Di\Di. Is this possible at all? Do you know of any examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Pimple, and am not entirely sure what you are asking, but here is some general information....

Zend Di acts as a [Service Locator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern), meaning that it maintains a registry of object instances and always returns the same instance of each object requested. So, you should easily be able to have Zend Di always return the same database connection (etc) without doing anything fancy, this is its default behaviour.

Injection of object properties/attributes isn't what you are doing in the example given; rather, the example looks like "constructor injection": injecting parameters/arguments at construction of the `mysqli` object. Constructor injection is well supported by Zend Di.

The creator of Zend Di, Ralph Schindler, has a thorough [repository of example use-cases](https://github.com/ralphschindler/Zend_DI-Examples) for Zend Di, where you should be able to find reference material for most things that you would like to do.

Specifically, perhaps what you are looking for is [Ralph's example here](https://github.com/ralphschindler/Zend_DI-Examples/blob/master/example-04.php), which utilizes constructor injection including configuration parameters.

All that said, many ZF2 devs prefer the Zend ServiceManager over Zend Di. The ServiceManager is the default for ZF2 and it also acts as a Service Locator, like Zend Di, but its usage is much more similar to Pimple. You will likely be much more at home with the ServiceManager if you are transitioning from Pimple.